# get failing condition in if statement

Tags: javascript

Consider the following if statement

```
if (a === null || b === null || c === null) {
    // I want the failing condition
}
```

is it possible to get the failing condition without the need of checking for every one of them

```
if (a === null || b === null || c === null) {
    if (a===null){alert('a failed the check');}
    if (b===null){alert('b failed the check');}
    if (c===null){alert('c failed the check');}
}
```

I know in above example it would be easy to make it dynamic, consider a real world example where different tests are performed.

Comment: why don't you do the each check first and store that in a variable.

Comment: you can use a function to check whether the variable is null or not which will minimise your code bytes though it needs same time

Comment: Check this answer, it addresses exactly the same need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32879829/921204

Comment: Wow nice find @techfoobar - I even looked for one before answering! #searchfail

Comment: @Jamiec - I could point it out *only* because I answered that other question a couple of hours ago and it was still fresh in memory.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible within an `if` block to get the condition which evaluated true.

Of course, because you've used `or` conditions your code could simply be

```
if (a===null){alert('a failed the check');}
else if (b===null){alert('b failed the check');}
else if (c===null){alert('c failed the check');}
```

Without the outer `if`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which condition is failed then you need to explicitly state that in your `if` condition else there is **no** way. Something like this:

```
if(a===null){alert('a failed the check');}
    else if (b===null){alert('b failed the check');}
    else {alert('c failed the check');}
```

**On a side note:**

When you are using the `||` operator then once the first `false` condition is met it does not checks the next conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar:

```
var failed = false;
if (a===null){alert('a failed the check');failed=true;}
if (b===null){alert('b failed the check');failed=true;}
if (c===null){alert('c failed the check');failed=true;}
if (failed) { /* common logic */ }
```